# Inline block adding extra space in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a webpage where I have stacked my div's with inline-Block properties. However, it adds extra spacing only between two div's in Firefox. The design is consistent in Safari and Chrome.

Here's the sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKtMk/) for that.

```
#main {
    display: block;
}
#sub11, #sub12, #sub21, #sub22,  #sub31, #sub32 {
    display: inline-block;
    background:red;
    padding:0;
    //margin-right:-4px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

Firefox adds extra space betweeb `GHI` and `TRY` row, while the ABC and GHI are consistent with other rows that comes after TRY.

Comment: Old question but still... I cannot find `TRY` row. Does the problem still exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following css fix exclusively for that one row

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #myRowID {margin-top:-5px;}
}
```

That solves my weird issue.

Answer (score 8):

The code:

```
 display: inline-block;
```

Will display spaces, you will have to add a float for them to appear directly after one another.

try adding a:

```
float:left;
```

to your #sub11, etc..

Comment: Using floats will require you to manually clear the floats which is still the major drawback. Floats are a bad idea especially in responsive design.

Comment: AHHH!!!  Spent two hours trying to track this down.  I'd plus one-million if I could.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Josh ha no problem bro. It only requires a float left because the above div will be floating left also and they need a direction to contain themselves.

Comment: Thanks :)  I was actually floating some `<li>` elements within a jQuery sortable.  For whatever reason, FF was adding extra spacing not visible in other browsers.  Your suggestion eliminated the extra spacing.. and the results are consistent across browsers.  You rock!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this question a dozen times theres an extensive article on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) about this.  This issue is when you use display: inline-block which is ussually for space element for paragraphs, now commonly used to inline objects. The best fix is on your css add this -4 margin-left and it should fix it. (dirty of course).

```
#sub11, #sub12, #sub21, #sub22 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    margin-left: -4px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

inline-block will respect white space between the elements. Easiest thing to do is add comment tags between your in-line elements

http://jsfiddle.net/YuMuC/1/

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="sub1">
        <div id="sub11">
            <div><h4>ABC</h4></div>
            <div>123</div>
        </div><!--
        --><div id="sub12">
            <div><h4>DEF</h4></div>
            <div>456</div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div id="sub2">
        <div id="sub21">
            <div><h4>GHI</h4></div>
            <div>745</div>
        </div><!--
        --><div id="sub22">
            <div><h4>JKL</h4></div>
            <div>987</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. And I have tried all of the ones mentioned on CSS trick. My problem is extra spacing in between only one of the specific rows and that too in firefox...

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working as intended. Since elements displayed as `inline-block` are supposed to go with the flow of text, spaces in your markup are considered for the output.

Solve this by commenting out the white space in the markup, or simply remove it all together, like this.

You could obviously also go ahead and display them as `block` and `float` them instead.